Do we need to set 'useConfirmHeader' when using spring cloud stream rabbit binder to enable publisher confirms
Do we need to set useConfirmHeader to true in the application.yml file if we want to enable publisher confirms using Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit Binder?
Seems publisher-confirms still work perfectly even if we remove this useConfirmHeader setting:
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output-out-0.producer.useConfirmHeader=true

Do we still need such a setting? When is it necessary?
Reference link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/rabbit/rabbit_overview/publisher-confirms.html#page-title

That's correct because the logic there is like this:
buildRabbitTemplate(extendedProperties,
                        errorChannel != null || extendedProperties.isUseConfirmHeader()));

Which donates to the mandatory. So, or this, or errorChannelEnabled, or errorHandlerDefinition is provided.
I don't see how else mandatory is set to true.
However see its JavaDocs:
/**
 * When true, the binding will complete the {@link java.util.concurrent.Future} field
 * in a {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CorrelationData} contained
 * in the
 * {@link org.springframework.amqp.support.AmqpHeaders#PUBLISH_CONFIRM_CORRELATION}
 * header when the confirmation is received.
 */
private boolean useConfirmHeader;

But I don't see that such a header is set somehow in Rabbit Binder. It is used from the AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint to extract user correlation data, but that's it. This  useConfirmHeader has not effect on a header interaction.
I believe the purpose of this option is cosmetic to indicate that confirms are going to be handled by the value in the AmqpHeaders.PUBLISH_CONFIRM_CORRELATION header.
Its further logic is to be mutually exclusive with a confirmAckChannel:
Assert.state(!StringUtils.hasText(extendedProperties.getConfirmAckChannel()),
                    "You cannot specify a 'confirmAckChannel' when 'useConfirmHeader' is true");

Which has been removed for a while.
